# How to add videojs event listener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video, video.js

I add [videojs](https://videojs.com/) player to my VUE app and I have no idea how to add event listener to it. I need to track when player starts playing and stop or pause. I can't find anything related to it, the documentation doesn't provide this.
Here is how my setup looks like according to [docs](https://videojs.com/guides/vue/)

```
this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options, () => {
    this.player.log('onPlayerReady', this);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is just

```
this.player.on('play', () => {
    this.play()
})
this.player.on('pause', () => {
    this.stop()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

VideoJS uses the HTML5 `<video>` element, so you can just use the [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events) associated with that element.

Example:

```js
document.querySelector(".video").addEventListener("play", (e) => {
  console.log("playing...");
});

document.querySelector(".video").addEventListener("pause", (e) => {
  console.log("paused...");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.1/video.min.js"></script>

<video class="video-js video" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],"loopbutton": true  }'>
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```